# Hanbrake audio annomalies with h.264 and AAC audio with large 9 GB source file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, handbrake

Using Handbrake 1.0.2
Source file is 9.3 GB AVI using h.264 codec lossless and AAC for audio
Source file plays fine in VLC, audio sounds perfect

When encoding source file to h.264 constant quality 32, AAC audio (avcodec), the audio has noticeable muffling every half a second or so.  It's really noticeable during a waterfall part but if I pay attention, it seems to be there throughout the entire video.  It seems like it happens when there is noise and it seems like the louder the noise, the more noticeable this repeating muffling is.  It's really noticeable during the waterfall part.

Using handbrake 1.0.1 and previewing the video, I tried changing to AAC passthrough, as well as other audio codecs and the audio corruption still happens during preview.  I also tried different bitrates and samplerates with the same result in preview.

Under handbrake 1.0.2 I used the default settings for AAC (avcodec) and during preview the sound was perfect.  Then when I encoded the entire file using the exact same settings, the audio corruption/muffling was there again.  This seems to suggest that handbrake has some issues with large files.  Not quite sure what's going on.

I need to be able to trust the encoding.  How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Have you tried with ffmpeg?

Comment: Not directly, but handbrake uses ffmpeg under the hood I believe.  Also I would prefer to use a simpler GUI app like handbrake then deal with command line options.  Having said that though, I don't have an issue with trying it command line as long as someone gives me all the parameters to get h.264 constant quality AAC audio.

Comment: There are many variables to try to weed out here, and it's hard to know what is going on without an easy, sure way to duplicate the issue. As for `ffmpeg`, I suppose you can just try encoding to AAC and see if that duplicates the issue: `ffmpeg -i input.avi -map 0:a:0 -c:a aac output.m4a`. Make sure to use a recent `ffmpeg`: see [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to binaries.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the command you gave and it seems like that worked.  The audio seems the same as the source video.  It's hard to tell or explain, but it almost seems like the audio is also kind of louder.  It's kind of like higher pitch when speaking in a tiny part with the waterfall, it like the audio makes certain syllables louder or almost cuts off syllables, but I only noticed it on one.  It's really hard to explain.  I'm not even sure if this is what is happening, but It sometimes kind of sounds like someone increased the volume on some parts but the waveform is cut off at peaks.

Comment: I checked if there was any sort of audio filter applied in handbrake, and I can't find any.  I don't even see any filters definable in handbrake.  Audio is set to AAC (avcodec) bitrate 192 mixdown stereo samplerate 48 DRC 0, Gain 0

Comment: I seemed to have fixed my problem though I'm not sure why I had to do this in the first place.  I had to change the "bitrate" dropdown for the audio to "quality" and I had to change the quality to "1".  I tried 5 and 10 and same result. The original audio should be at 48000 sample rate and 192 bitrate.  I tried those settings, same corruption.  I tried bitrate 512 (max) and samplerate 48 (max) and same issues.  I'm glad I got it to work but I still have a question of why the audio is such poor quality when I use AAC passthrough or AAC(avcodec) with 48 and 192 for bitrate (same as source)?